# How can I upload file from string in playframework?

Tags: scala, playframework

PlayFramework docs shows that it is easy to upload a file.

https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.5.x/ScalaWS

```
ws.url(url).post(Source(FilePart("hello", "hello.txt", Option("text/plain"), FileIO.fromFile(tmpFile)) :: DataPart("key", "value") :: List()))
```

But what if the file content is already in memory? Any alternative method for `FileIO.fromFile`, such as FileIO.fromString(jsontStr)?

```
val jsonStr = """{ foo: "Bar"} """
ws.url(url).post(Source(FilePart("hello", "hello.json", Option("application/json"), FileIO.fromString(jsonStr)) :: DataPart("key", "value") :: List()))
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All you need is a `FilePart` that has a `Source[ByteString]` as ref.
Just use

```
Source.single(ByteString(jsonStr))
```

as the ref part.

Comment: Thanks for your quick answer!